# Limiting checked checkbox function not working as expected

Tags: html, typescript, checkbox

I have tried to implement a function into my checkbox question where only 3 checkboxes  can be checked. However, it will still continue to check beyond the limit (3).

I am certain it has something to do with **latestcheck.checked = false;**

My typescript function:

```
factors(whichlist, maxchecked, latestcheck) {
// An array containing the id of each checkbox to monitor. 
var listone = new Array("teamStrength", "marketOp", "productOff", "technology", "financialPerform", "coinvestors", "mediaExpo", "awardsWon", "portfolioFit");

// End of customization.
var iterationlist;
eval("iterationlist=" + whichlist);
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < iterationlist.length; i++) {
  if ((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(iterationlist[i])).checked == true) { 
    count++;

  }
  if (count > maxchecked) { 
    latestcheck.checked = false; 
    console.log("last checked: " + latestcheck.checked); 
  }
}
if (count > maxchecked) {
  alert('Sorry, only ' + maxchecked + ' may be checked.');
}
```

}

What needs to happen is that after the alert pops out, the checkbox that I checked (after the limit of 3, so the fourth checked box) will be unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do this? (I do not do TypeScript)

```
const listOne = ["teamStrength", "marketOp", "productOff", "technology", "financialPerform", "coinvestors", "mediaExpo", "awardsWon", "portfolioFit"];    
const container = document.getElementById("checkboxContainer");
container.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if (listOne.indexOf(e.target.id) !=-1) { // may not even be needed
    if (container.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 3) {
      e.preventDefault(); // or this.checked=false;
    }
  }
});
```

Simplified:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".question").forEach(function(q) {
  q.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var len = this.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (len > 3) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="question">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't id have to be unique? if yes, how would i implement checkBoxContainer since each checkbox will need its own unique id?

Comment: Since you did not post your html, I just guess at the ID of whatever is the parent of all the checkboxes. It could be document.body too. The container in my script is whatever is the nearest container that holds all the checkboxes. If there are no other checkboxes on the page, then we do not even need the array. Then `if (document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 3)`  is a good enough test

Comment: my html contains a question which has a total of 9 checkbox options. one of it is: `<label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="productOff" class="checkbox" name="factors" (click)="factors('listOne',3,this)" value="3" (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.discussionMode)">
                                        Product/service offering
             </label>`

Comment: @mhfour Just add the alert after `e.preventDefault()` since you want some alert.